# How to solve the integral $\int \frac {x^2} {x^4-2x^2-8} \ d x$?

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8} \ d x$$

How to present?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: **MASSIVE HINT:** Try using partial fractions.

Comment: Any reason why this question gets three answers? No details...ano own attempts...no thoughts...???

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+2)(x-2)(x+2)}=\frac{1}{3(x^2+2)}-\frac{1}{6(x+2)}+\frac{1}{6(x-2)}$$

So:

$$\int\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}\space\text{d}x=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2}\space\text{d}x-\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{x+2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{1}{6}\int\frac{1}{x-2}\space\text{d}x$$

Answer (score 1):

First, one may observe that
$$
x^4-2x^2-8=(x^2-1)^2-9=[(x^2-1)-3][(x^2-1)+3]=(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2)
$$ giving
$$
\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}=\frac{x^2}{(x-2)(x+2)(x^2+2)}=\frac{1}{6 (x-2)}-\frac{1}{6 (x+2)}+\frac{1}{3 \left(x^2+2\right)}
$$ then
$$
\int\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}\:dx=\frac16\int\frac{dx}{x-2}-\frac16\int\frac{dx}{x+2}+\frac13\int\frac{dx}{\left(x^2+2\right)}
$$ which is easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I = \int\frac{x^2}{x^4-2x^2-8}dx =\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2-1)^2-3^2}dx$$

So $$I = \int\frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2+2)}dx = \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{2(x^2+2)+(x^2-4)}{(x^2-4)(x^2+2)}dx$$

So $$I = \frac{2}{3}\int\frac{1}{x^2-4}dx+\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2}dx$$

So $$I = \frac{2}{12}\int\left[\frac{1}{x-2}-\frac{1}{x+2}\right]dx+\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{1}{x^2+2}dx$$

$$I = \frac{1}{6}\left(\ln|x-2|-\ln|x+2|\right)+\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$